# vmware esxi - vmkfstools returns error when trying to copy thin vmdk

Tags: vmware-esxi

When trying to copy a thin vmdk on esxi 5 using vmkfstools like this:

```
vmkfstools -i IPFire-flat.vmdk -d thin IPFire-Template-flat.vmdk
```

I get this error:

> DiskLib_Check() failed for source disk. The file specified is not a
>   virtual disk (15).

I can perfectly use the vmdk in my vm so I am not exactly sure what is wrong.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `vmkfstools`, you need to target the small `IPFire.vmdk` file, not the `-flat.vmdk` file.  Leave `-flat` out of the destination file name as well.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. Thought I had to do it the other way and just `cp` the file without flat because the flat-file is the big one appearantly storing the data.